# Force browser to wait for a long running server script to finish from client side

Tags: javascript, html, browser, firebug

We have a website which generates a csv file of a group's order history. 
The script is slow and for groups that have placed a lot of orders, the request isn't completed
- i.e. after around 10 mins, the status of the request shows up as `(Aborted)` in Firebug

**First question:** where is the `(Aborted)` status sent from? e.g. is it the server saying it's given up or a timeout from the browser or something else

**Second question:** if it's something that can be controlled client-side, how could I force the browser to wait for a response?

**Please note:** I have no access to the server-side scripts and have limited access to content/javascript.

And, in case you're wondering, the point of this is we want all of our data out of that website because we've built a replacement. The company that maintains it (or what's left of the company anyway) is too clueless to send us that information in any other way.

Comment: do you have to use a browser?

Comment: i dont really think/believe it has anything to do with the browser, i am pretty sure its php (or alternative) run time limitation or memory limitation or even sql limitation.  i have not yet run into a situation where browser or JS stop scripts

Comment: Good luck getting users to wait 10 minutes for their page to paint.  One question - are you going to try to prevent them from closing the browser, too?

Comment: the post does not mention PHP

Comment: Question 1: Does it show an error code next to (Aborted)? Aborted itself normally is Firebug's client side death, but from your description it sounds like it's a server side issue.

Comment: Hi just to clarify, we just want the data the csv files generate. We had no hand in developing the website and no access to modify it aside from certain sections where we can modify text/insert javascript. @STLDeveloper It's a poorly developed system, which is why we're replacing it. As long as this generated report works the one time for me, I'm happy, then we can shut it down for good.

Comment: @Dolondro there's no error that I can see (I'm looking at the Status column under the Net tab in Firebug - point me in the right direction if I should be looking elsewhere). Unforunately, there's no way for me to access any php error reporting to confirm if it is a server-side issue.